# How do you test and save filters in Gmail New Look?

Tags: gmail-filters

It seems that with the change to the Gmail UI, the filter creation function is merely a pop-down menu.  If I actually try to test a filter, it'll show me the results... but only once.  After showing the results, the pop-down menu disappears and the filter I was testing is lost.

There's no way to actually test filters or edit existing filters.

Answer (score 1):

Once created

[image: Gmail new filters]

It's still around, click on the dropdown

[image: Yep, still there]

And if you're coming in later, the [Settings/Filters](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#settings/filters) option's still around where you can edit it.

[image: yep, can edit]

Comment: No I mean if I click on "edit" and actually change something and then press "Test Search", it will just take me to search results and my previous change is lost because the drop down menu disappears AND the search box is blank.  Now I have to click the back button and edit it AGAIN.  Is that not the case for you?

Comment: @Jack I see what you mean - same case for me too. Probably worthwhile to use the [Send feedback](http://www.google.com/support/bin/request.py?hl=en&contact_type=surveyk&product=gmail) option

Answer (score 0):

How wonderful you are to use Google Script for the latest Gmail filters. I tried it and succeeded as expected.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/

Example for an automatic filter in Gmail using Google script: filter reply@abc.com, subject: for sale, older_than: 1d to move trash= 
[Remove old emails from Gmail matching criteria automatically](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/127207/remove-old-emails-from-gmail-matching-criteria-automatically/127244#127244) 

To make own filter from Gmail: 
[image] 
Then Click "Filters and blocked addresses" 
Then Click "Create a new filter" 
[image] 
Fill in the necessary, 
[image] 
Then Click "Create Filter" 
[image] 
Don't forget to wait for the process to run for a few seconds until there is a notification of success. don't hurry