# Remove old emails from Gmail matching criteria automatically

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I want to delete the following emails:

> from:(reply@abc.com) subject:(for sale) older_than:1d

It seems in the old Gmail interface it was possible to create filters to delete these messages. I am not sure in the current Gmail interface (2019) how we can do this. I can search these emails but once I click create filter, the `older_than` part disappears.

For the old interface there are guidelines like [this](https://duntuk.com/how-create-gmail-filter-automatically-delete-emails-older-x-amount-days).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Google Script: 
1. Go to: https://script.google.com
2. Click "New Script"
3. Type this code

```
// reference: https://medium.com/@fw3d/a-cleaning-robot-for-your-gmail-inbox-f44c01306ea2
// Modify by: Dicky Ibrohim for delete (move to trash) specific subject, sender, and time

function removetotrash() {

  var delayDays = 1; // Impact form email more than 1day
  var maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setDate(maxDate.getDate()-delayDays); 

  // What will be executed, adjust the string here
  var searches = [
    '"for sale" from:reply@abc.com'
    ];

  // Looping for 100 last email
  var threads = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < searches.length; i++) {
    var tmp_threads = GmailApp.search(searches[i], 0, 100); // search until 100 mail
    var threads = threads.concat(tmp_threads);
  }

  // Then remove all
  for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
    if (threads[i].getLastMessageDate()<maxDate)
    {
      threads[i].moveToTrash();
    }
  }
}
```

4. click File --> Save
5. Make it automation, click on menu "Current project’s triggers",
6. Click "Create New triger"
7. Setup hour time, example, script will executed every 3 hours
8. Save.

I tried it and it went well

---

Manual Work from Gmail

[image]

Then
[image]

Then
[image]

Do this carefully. when you press the blue button, there is a loading process to complete (Don't do anything until there is a marker successfully).

Then
[image]
Then check result
[image]

Comment: It worked for the first time I created it, but not afterward. So on the next days, I can see emails older than 1d.

Comment: You can use Google Apps Script with exact above filter.

Comment: I have added Google Script in the answer. I tried it and it worked, please try and have a good luck @apadana

Comment: @DICKYIBROHIM Thanks!

Comment: There is an error when I run the script: 
Exception: Service invoked too many times for one day: gmail.
removetotrash